# Android 4.0+ RemoteControlClient MetadataEditor Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-mediaplayer, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I bought my new car I noticed that it had a screen that showed metadata information about the music playing through the Bluetooth audio sink.  It worked for some apps, but notably not with the app I primary use for listening to music.  After some research, and reading posts from this site and some others I was able to determine that this works if the app implements the ICS lockscreen controls with RemoteControlClient and MetadataEditor.

Since the app I use is open source I was able to download the source code and see that the app did not use the RemoteControlClient.  my next step was to look at the Google Sample code for Random Music Player and test this on my phone and car.  This worked successfully and I proceeded to modify the existing source code for the app I am working on.  I copied the RemoteControlClientCompat and RemoteControlHelper Classes into my project and copied the code using these classes into my project's code as best as possible.

Since doing this I have successfully implemented Audio Focus management, Media Button Controls, and the RemoteControlClient / MetadataEditor.  The lock screen controls are working and functioning perfectly, however my car still does NOT show the Metadata.  Again the BT metadata works with the sample code, but not with my app, and the lock screen controls work without issue on both apps.

Anyone out there have any idea as to why the lock screen controls would work, but the Bluetooth Metadata would not?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Exactly same issue here. Have you found anything?

Comment: Could you post some example code.  If your phone supports AVRCP 1.3 it should work if done correctly.  AVRCP 1.3 support is newly available in Android 4.3.  There are certain older android phones that some handset manufacturers have added AVRCP 1.3 support on their own.  From my experience it will work on Motorola Razor phones running android 4.1.x.